# Claim in Rudin 3.36

Tags: real-analysis

On p68 he claims:

> More precisely: Whenever the ratio test shows convergence, the root test does too; **whenever the root test is inconclusive, the ratio 
>   test is  too**.

I'm having trouble seeing why this is true. Consider the series $a_n = 1$. Then by theorem 3.33 (c) on p65 the root test is inconclusive. But by theorem 3.34 (b) on p66 the ratio test shows divergence. Isn't this a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation is correct. The fact that 
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = 1
\end{equation}
does imply that the root test gives no information, according to Theorem 3.35 (c).

Since
\begin{equation}
\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert \geq 1,
\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N},
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation}
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert \geq 1,
\end{equation}
Theorem 3.34 (b) indeed concludes that $\sum a_n$ diverges. One can also easily see this from $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0$.

So the issue is about interpretation of Rudin's Remarks 3.36 on page 68. I think that he meant to say that based on $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert\geq 1$ alone, the ratio test as in Theorem 3.34 says nothing about the convergence or divergence of $\sum a_n$. One can confirm this from context, specifically, the examples that he gave in 3.35.

Comment: Note that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert = 1$  does not imply that $\sum a_n$ diverges! See, e.g., $\sum \frac1n$ and $\sum \frac1{n^2}$, as Rudin has suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In your example *both* tests are inconclusive:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\root n\of a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\root n\of 1=1,$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1}=1.$$

Comment: See p66 Theorem 3.34 (b).

Comment: @ignoramus, in p68 is saying that if both limits exists, then are equal. The specific case of 3.34 (b) isn't covered.

Answer (score 2):

As usual Rudin (requiescat in pace) is a bit cryptic and expects a lot from his readers.  The series of exercises *Ex  3.6.7-3.6.16* in  [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/com/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf) elaborates on this theme (but we flagged some of them as "advanced"--if you are studying Rudin  then you are advanced!).  If Rudin annoys you occasionally then perhaps you might find the equivalent material here a bit less so.